# How to get filtered record from entity framework and store it in model class

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

> I am using As.net MVC with entity Framework  I dont want to use for
>   each operator below in var results it would be done easily but here the
>   matter is is it possible to get the filtered record and store it in
>   NewsModel object so that i can get only filter record

```
    public NewsModel GetNewsDetails(int Id)
    {
        NewsModel newsModel = new NewsModel();

        var db = new elastomerupdateEntities();
        var results = db.News.Where(newsType => newsType.id == Id);

        return newsModel;


    }
```

Thanks in advance any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public NewsModel GetNewsDetails(int Id)
{
    NewsModel newsModel = new NewsModel();

    var db = new elastomerupdateEntities();
    newsModel = db.News.Where(x=> x.id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

    return newsModel ; 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer as shown by @Deadlock only difference is im using Model Class NewsModel which is not equal to News class which is created by entity framework since query return Entity table class object i consume it and assigned to NewsModel class as below

```
public NewsModel GetNewsDetails(int Id)
        {
            NewsModel newsModel = new NewsModel();

            var db = new elastomerupdateEntities();
            var newsObj = db.News.Where(newsType => newsType.id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

            newsModel.HeadLine = newsObj.headline;
            newsModel.Details = newsObj.details;


            return newsModel;


        }
```